# Integral of a logarithmic derivative of a complex polynomial over the real line

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a complex polynomial with $n$ zeros in $y>0$, $m$ zeros in $y<0$, and no real zeros. How can we show that
$$\displaystyle\lim_{R\to + \infty}\displaystyle\int_{-R}^R \dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\pi i (n-m)?$$
If $R$ is large enough so that all the zeros are inside $|z|<R$, then we can apply the argument principle to get $\int_{C_1} f'(z)/f(z)~dz=2\pi i n$ and $\int_{C_2} f'(z)/f(z)~dz=2\pi i m$ where $C_1$ is the half circle $Re^{it}, 0\leq t\leq \pi$ with $[-R,R]$, and $C_2$ is the half circle $Re^{it}, -\pi\leq t\leq 0$ with $[R,-R]$. But I think I need more information to get the result. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $C_R^+$ and $C_R^-$ are the upper and lower semicircle with radius $R$ (in positive orientation) then (as you already observed)
$$
 \int_{C_R^+}  \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz +  \int_{-R}^R \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \, dx 
= 2\pi i n \\
 \int_{C_R^-}  \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz -  \int_{-R}^R \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \, dx 
= 2\pi i m 
$$
for sufficiently large $R$. It follows that
$$
2 \int_{-R}^R \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} + \int_{C_R^+}  \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz - 
\int_{C_R^-}  \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz = 2 \pi (n-m) \, .
$$
The “missing link” is that
$$
\tag{*}
 \lim_{R \to \infty} \left(\int_{C_R^+}  \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz - 
\int_{C_R^-}  \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz \right) = 0
$$
and that follows from the asymptotic
$$ 
 \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{d}{z} + O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)
$$
for $z \to \infty$, where $d$ is the degree of the polynomial: Both integrals in $(*)$ are asymptotically equal to $\pi i d$.